# Merge array values - vuejs

Tags: arrays, vue.js, merge

I want a new array based on the existing array. Basically, I am training to create Shopify variants based on textbox value. Right now what I am doing is to separate the textbox value by a comma and save in the array. Based on that arrays, I want a new variant array.

Variant arrays:-

```
variant_size  = ['small','medium','big'];
variant_color = ['red','blue','green'];
variant_material = [];
variant_style = ['style1','style2'];
```

My expected output:-

```
new_array = [
{'small','red','style1'}
{'small','red','style2'}
{'small','blue','style1'}
{'small','blue','style2'}
{'small','green','style1'}
{'small','green','style2'}
{'medium','red','style1'}
{'medium','red','style2'}
{'medium','blue','style1'}
{'medium','blue','style2'}
{'medium','green','style1'}
{'medium','green','style2'}
{'big','red','style1'}
{'big','red','style2'}
{'big','blue','style1'}
{'big','blue','style2'}
{'big','green','style1'}
{'big','green','style2'}
];
```

If the array is empty like variant_material in the above example, skip that array. Below is a screenshot of the textbox which I have.

[This is what I am training to acchive](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IhOeP.png) and [This is my text fields](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mzZBa.png).

Comment: `[{'small','medium','big'}]` etc is not valid. what have you tried to generate your expected output?

Comment: `axios.post('/productData')
                    .then(response => {
          this.variant_size     = response.data.variants.variant_size.split(",");
                        this.variant_color    = response.data.variants.variant_color.split(",");
}); 

let variant_size = [{'variant_size' : this.variant_size}];
let variant_color = [{'variant_color' : this.variant_color}];`

what I am doing right now is fetch the textbox value and slipt by comma and store into the array

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, simply loop over each array you want to make permutations for.

You need to change the source array and the expected output, as both are not valid javascript.

```js
// object of variant's
const variant = {
  size: ['small', 'medium', 'big'],
  color: ['red', 'blue', 'green'],
  material: [],
  style: ['style1', 'style2']
}

// loop
let variants = []
for (let size of variant.size)
  for (let color of variant.color)
    for (let style of variant.style)
      variants.push([size, color, style])

// result
console.log(JSON.stringify(variants, null, 2))
```

Comment: How can I check if the array is undefined in the loop

`variant_color: [Array(3)]
variant_material: [undefined]
variant_size: [Array(3)]
variant_style: [undefined]
variant_title: [undefined]`

Comment: how are you making that?

Comment: Please review my code.
https://www.awesomescreenshot.com/image/5480266/6d4152df95735c6089090ea004947098

Comment: In the above code, you didn't mention material in for loop. how can I skip the for loop for an empty array?